# how to handle Flickr Exception

Tags: java, file, exception, flickr

I have a list of Images Ids crawled from Flickr web site

I need to get its location (latitude & longitude )

This is my code

```
File source = //images id 
File target = // images location

Scanner scanner = null;
PrintStream pStream =null;
String apiKey = //;
Flickr flick = new Flickr(apiKey);

PhotosInterface photosInterface=    flick.getPhotosInterface();
try {
    scanner= new Scanner(source);
    pStream= new PrintStream(target);       
    while (scanner.hasNext())
    {       
        String line = scanner.nextLine();       
        if (photosInterface.getPhoto(line).getGeoData()!=null)
        {
            pStream.println(Float.toString(photosInterface.getPhoto(line).getGeoData().getLatitude())+"\t"+Float.toString(photosInterface.getPhoto(line).getGeoData().getLongitude()));
        }
        else pStream.println("null");
    }           
    System.out.println(lineNumber);
}
catch (Exception e) {
}

}
```

In this case I want to execute this instruction

```
pStream.println("null");
```

in case of:

images are not available ( FlickrException)

or the image is not associated with GeoData

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you need to surround the call that throws a `FlickrException` in a `try {..} catch` block.

For example, if `photosInterface.getPhoto(line)` could throw a `FlickrException` when no images are available then :

```
while (scanner.hasNext())
{       
    String line = scanner.nextLine();       
    try {
        if (photosInterface.getPhoto(line).getGeoData()!=null)
        {
            pStream.println(Float.toString(photosInterface.getPhoto(line).getGeoData().getLatitude())+"\t"+Float.toString(photosInterface.getPhoto(line).getGeoData().getLongitude()));
        }
        else pStream.println("null");
    } catch (FlickrException fe) {
        // You may need to check something about the exception
        // here in case it can be thrown for a different reason
        // than images are not available 
        pStream.println("null");
    }
}           
System.out.println(lineNumber);
```

Comment: I tried this code
the excution is stopped after printing the first "null"